# Minimize $\int_0^1 |(xf(x))'|(1+x) dx$ over nonnegative $f$ satisfying $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, calculus-of-variations

Let $f$ be a nonnegative continuously differentiable function on $[0,1]$ with $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$ and $f(1) = 0$.

> How small
> $$C_f := \int_0^1 |(xf(x))'|(1+x) dx$$
> can be? In particular, is it possible to choose $f$ such that $C_f < 1$?

For similar problems I usually use the Euler-Lagrange equation, but here I do not know what to do with the absolute value under the integral. Are there any methods for dealing with such problems?

Comment: What happens if you just assume $(xf(x))'\leq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: One can make $C_f$ arbitrarily small, but not reach $0$.

If one wants to make $C_f$ small, one should choose
$f$ such that $|(xf(x))'|$ is small for most $x$.

For a constant $a>0$, we choose
$$
g_a(x):=\frac{1}{x+a} - \frac{1}{1+a},
\quad
b_a := \int_0^1 g_a(x) \mathrm dx,
\quad
f_a(x):=b_a^{-1} g_a(x).
$$
Then $f$ should satisfy the requirements.
We also have $b_a\to\infty$ as $a\to 0$.

Using estimates, one can then calculate that
$
C_{f_a} \to0
$
holds as $a\to 0$
(I think this is mostly because of $b_a^{-1}\to0$, while the rest can be bounded).

On the other hand, $C_f=0$ is not possible, because then $xf(x)$ would need to be constant.
However, this is not possible for a continuously differentiable function
on $[0,1]$.